# why local variable is different parameter at anonymous function in goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
)

func main() {
  runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
  fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))

  // s := "hello world \n"

  for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    go func(n int) {
        fmt.Println(n, i)
    }(i)
  }

  fmt.Scanln()
}
```

I just wondering why `n` is not equal to `i` every go routine.

Also `i` sometimes has the same value as in the previous call.

What is the matter in this code?

Answer (score 9):

This topic is well covered (across multiple languages) - but the short version is this:

Your current output is like this:

```
1 100
2 100
3 100
4 100
...
```

The variable `i` becomes part of a closure. This means that its value actually outlasts its scope (its moved off to the side so that when the goroutine executes it knows where to find `i`).

By the time the scheduler gets around to executing your goroutines, the `for` loop has finished and the value of `i` is going to be 100 (or close to it if you're running on a slow machine).

The fix is to store the value every iteration and use that:

```
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    x := i            // <------ Store the value of i each loop iteration
    go func(n int) {
        fmt.Println(n, x) // <---- Use the new, local, closed over value, not the main closed over one
    }(i)
}
```

Now every goroutine references its own copy of a closed over variable `x`, and your output becomes:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
...
```

This phenomenon is not isolated to Go.

You can see a working sample on the playground:
[<kbd>View it on the Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/OT39us6AQ3)